# Using UILabel Setfont in IOS 7 is throwing an autolayout NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, uilabel, font-size

I have an app which works for iOS 6. However, when trying to run it on iOS 7 I have encountered a problem for code that tries to change the font programmatically.
The line causing the problem is:
[topHandScoreGogglesLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];

topHandScoreGogglesLabel is a UILabel with font of type "System" and size 14

fontSize is an int of value 12.

The exception I'm getting is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. TurnViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'

If I comment this line out the view is presented, but when I add back the line I get the exception again.

I do need to change the font size programmatically as I use different sizes based on device type (iPad vs. iPhone).
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Shlomi

Answer (score -1):

IOS 7 is still in beta mode. There for you cannot discuss regarding IOS 7 problems in public, according to the NDA. I suggest to put this problem in Apple forum.

Comment: I guess now IOS 7 has been released for public. So kindly give any thought about this issue. as i am having the same issue.